# ReactiveCommand never hooks up the event handler for the canExecute observable

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

In my test case I can verify that the event handler `CollectionChanged` gets hooked up correctly. This occurrs when the command is created. In my view model when I do the same thing the event handler is never hooked up. Why is this?

If I make an explicit call to `Undo.CanExecute(null)` in my view model it will hook up the event handler. I guess I should not have to do this and that something must be wrong with my view model code.

## View Model

```
ActionManager = new ActionManager();    

var canUndo = Observable
    .FromEventPattern(e => ActionManager.CollectionChanged += e, e => ActionManager.CollectionChanged -= e)
    .Select(_ => ActionManager.CanUndo)
    ;

Undo = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(canUndo, UndoAsync);
```

## Test Case

```
public class MiscTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanExecute()
    { 
        var am = new ActionManager();
        var canUndo = Observable
            .FromEventPattern(e => am.CollectionChanged += e, e => am.CollectionChanged -= e)
            .Select(_ => am.CanUndo);

        var command = ReactiveCommand.Create(canUndo);

        var action = new CallMethodAction(() => { }, () => { });
        var canExecute = command.CanExecute(null);
        canExecute.Should().BeFalse();
        am.Execute(action);
        canExecute = command.CanExecute(null);
        canExecute.Should().BeTrue();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, your view model code is most likely correct.

What you managed to observe is a lazy nature of Rx observables in action. Digging the source code of [`ReactiveCommand` constructor](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs#L323) reveals that `canExecute` observable you provide to `CreateAsyncTask` factory method is not subscribed immediately, but instead [`Publish` is called](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs#L341), which returns [`IConnectableObservable`](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect), which is stored in a private field (`this.canExecute`). So, the `ReactiveCommand` starts to actually listen to `canExecute` changes, when [`Connect`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html) is called on `this.canExecute`. This happens in [`CanExecute(object parameter)` method](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs#L449).

So, should you explicitly call `ReactiveCommand's` `CanExecute` in your ViewModel? No, because this should be done by your `View` framework when you bind your command to an actual button.